# Link to static css in Yesod 0.9.3.2

Tags: yesod

I'm following along with the yesod tutorial on the yesod wiki, and hitting a wall linking to an external css framework (blueprint).

I created the site using the scaffolding tool, and everything has been working correctly so far using 'yesod devel'.

I've downloaded the blueprint files into static/css/blueprint and added the following to default-layout-wrapper.hamlet:

```
!!!
<html>
    <head
        <title>#{pageTitle pc}
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css media=screen href=@{StaticR css_blueprint_screen_css}>
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css media=print href=@{StaticR css_blueprint_print_css}>
        ^{pageHead pc}
    <body
        ^{pageBody pc}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Foundation.hs:98:27:
    Not in scope: `css_blueprint_screen_css'
    In the result of the splice:
      $(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
    To see what the splice expanded to, use -ddump-splices
    In the first argument of `hamletToRepHtml', namely
      `$(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")'
    In the expression:
      hamletToRepHtml
        ($(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet"))

Foundation.hs:98:27:
    Not in scope: `css_blueprint_print_css'
    In the result of the splice:
      $(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
    To see what the splice expanded to, use -ddump-splices
    In the first argument of `hamletToRepHtml', namely
      `$(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")'
    In the expression:
      hamletToRepHtml
        ($(hamletFile "hamlet/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet"))
Starting development server...
```

I'm on a Mac, running ghc-7.0.3... I thought I understand how StaticR works, but I'm obviously missing something. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Neil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need to `touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs`? In general, `yesod devel` or `yesod build` will handle that for you automatically, but it's the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: That worked, thanks Michael. I'm not sure why it wasn't handled automatically, but see if I can figure it out as I learn more.

Comment: I have same problem, Michael. I put my main.css file in static/css folder, but Yesod doesn't see it, and I get error: Not in scope: ‘css_main_css’. What can I do?

Comment: @DenisShevchenko did you try what my answer suggested, and `touch Settings/StaticFiles.hs`?